# ReactJS detect when an element is outside parent div

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of elements and I want to display them in a div, when the array is big some elements are outside my parent div, I want to detect which ones are outside to make some operations.

this is my example :

```js
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "test1" },
    { id: 2, name: "test2" },
    { id: 3, name: "test3" },
    { id: 4, name: "test4" },
    { id: 5, name: "test5" },
    { id: 6, name: "test6" },
    { id: 7, name: "test7" },
    { id: 8, name: "test8" }
  ];
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "120px",
        background: "red",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      {data.map((el) => (
        <div key={el.id}>{el.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

For the moment I get this :
[image]

So, the output should be :

```
{ id: 7, name: "test7" },
{ id: 8, name: "test8" }
```

the goal of this is to display in parent ONLY the elements that parent can support to display, forthe others I will display it in other div

Comment: Isn't just a CSS issue ? what about adding `overflow:hidden` on the parent div ?

Comment: @SteveB It is, but his desired goal is to get/detect the data that is outside of the red box.

Comment: I'm curious. I wonder what is the actual requirement

Answer (score 1):

To detect which elements are outside the parent div, you can make use of React refs and DOM measurements.

```
   import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
  const [visibleItems, setVisibleItems] = useState([]);
  const [parentHeight, setParentHeight] = useState(0); // New state for parent height
  const data = Array.from(new Array(10)).map((el, i) => ({
    id: i,
    name: `test ${i}`
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (parentRef.current) {
        const newParentHeight = parentRef.current.clientHeight;
        if (newParentHeight !== parentHeight) {
          setParentHeight(newParentHeight);
          const children = Array.from(parentRef.current.children);
          let totalHeight = 0;
          let visibleItems = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            totalHeight += children[i].clientHeight;
            if (totalHeight <= newParentHeight) {
              visibleItems.push(data[i]);
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          setVisibleItems(visibleItems);
        }
      }
    };

    handleResize();
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, [parentHeight, data]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={parentRef}
      style={{
        height: "520px",
        background: "red",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        overflow: "hidden"
      }}
    >
      {visibleItems.map((el) => (
        <VisibleItems key={el.id} visibleItems={visibleItems} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const VisibleItems = ({ visibleItems }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{visibleItems}</p>
      {visibleItems.map((el) => (
        <div key={el.id}>{el.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Te idea is clear thank you, but the code not work.. I'm trying it here : https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-volhard-d72ncl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It's infinite re-render @Muhammad Idrees, I can't see anything when Copy/Paste your code in my sandbox..

Comment: updated again @alainber82

Comment: Not worked... please see this I explain in very well in a different way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76836406/how-can-i-detect-if-a-div-children-is-outside-the-parent-div-because-of-length

Answer (score 0):

Since your parent div is fixed height of 120px, if you give the children fixed height as well then you can easily calculate the children that will contain inside the parent.
if child height is 30px, then the parent can only contain 120/30= 4 children.

I don't think there is any specific way to detect a child overflowing it's parent.

Comment: My childrens will not have the same height sometimes..