# How can I detect if a div children is outside the parent div because of length?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent div with blue background and black border (the width is 650px fixed).

My array data looks like :

```
  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "banana", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 11, name: "r", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 12, name: "dsfgh", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 13, name: "jjhjh", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 14, name: "rsrse", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 15, name: "tyfh", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 16, name: "sfss", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 17, name: "azee", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 20, name: "oriented", category: "legs" },
    { id: 21, name: "orio", category: "legs" },
    { id: 22, name: "balance", category: "legs" },
    { id: 23, name: "navigo", category: "legs" },
    { id: 24, name: "href", category: "legs" },
    { id: 25, name: "john", category: "legs" },
    { id: 3, name: "lovanica", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 4, name: "biceps", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 5, name: "interior", category: "legs" },
    { id: 6, name: "avocado", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 7, name: "triceps", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 70, name: "tri", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 71, name: "avant", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 72, name: "delto", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 73, name: "lateral", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 74, name: "latos", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 75, name: "vini", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 8, name: "pomme", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 9, name: "framboi", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 10, name: "varius", category: "legs" }
  ];
```

Like you see, each item have a category, so I'm trying to display id in my parent div like this :

[image]

And it's done by my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const parentRef = useRef(null);

  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: "banana", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 11, name: "r", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 20, name: "oriented", category: "legs" },
    { id: 21, name: "orio", category: "legs" },
    { id: 22, name: "balance", category: "legs" },
    { id: 23, name: "navigo", category: "legs" },
    { id: 24, name: "href", category: "legs" },
    { id: 25, name: "john", category: "legs" },
    { id: 3, name: "lovanica", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 4, name: "biceps", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 5, name: "interior", category: "legs" },
    { id: 6, name: "avocado", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 7, name: "triceps", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 70, name: "tri", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 71, name: "avant", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 72, name: "delto", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 73, name: "lateral", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 74, name: "latos", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 75, name: "vini", category: "muscles" },
    { id: 8, name: "pomme", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 9, name: "framboi", category: "fruit" },
    { id: 10, name: "varius", category: "legs" }
  ];

  console.log(data);
  const fruit = data.filter((el) => el.category === "fruit");
  const legs = data.filter((el) => el.category === "legs");
  const muscles = data.filter((el) => el.category === "muscles");

  return (
    <div
      ref={parentRef}
      className="parent"
      style={{
        background: "blue",
        height: "100px",
        width: "650px",
        display: "flex",
        border: "2px solid black"
      }}
    >
      <div className="fruit">
        {fruit.map((el) => (
          <div className="child">{el.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="legs">
        {legs.map((el) => (
          <div className="child">{el.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="muscles">
        {muscles.map((el) => (
          <div className="child">{el.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The problem I got is when my data is growing, some div gonna be outside the blue div (parent), so the solution is to select all data that gonna be outside my parent div because I want to create another div with it, so for this example :

[image]

As you can see : `lateral,latos,vini` are outside the parent div, so the output should be :

```
{ id: 73, name: "lateral", category: "muscles" },
{ id: 74, name: "latos", category: "muscles" },
{ id: 75, name: "vini", category: "muscles" },
```

I want to create function to do this and avoid DOM manipulations, but I don't have any idea how to achieve this..

I've create a [sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-haze-9f3v3q?file=/src/App.js:1248-1401).

Comment: I can't avoid thinking this sounds more like a CSS issue than a React issue, I'm pretty sure you should be able to achieve this with some CSS ninja work. But having more context would really help to give you a better answer. i.e. How dynamic are the red and cyan blocks (specifically the width)? Based on the code you provided they have static widths and you could just calculate it and create a new div for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you would like the overflowing children to stay inside the parent container and be accessible via horizontal scrolling.

You can achieve this by applying the `overflow-x: auto;` style to the parent div.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div
        className="parent"
        style={{
          background: "blue",
          height: "100px",
          width: "500px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          overflowX: "auto", // Add this
        }}
      >
        {/* Your children here */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

This will enable a horizontal scrollbar for the parent container when the child elements' combined width exceeds the parent's width. All the children will remain inside the parent container and be accessible by scrolling.
---------------update------------------
gotcha
try this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef,useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
 

  useEffect(() => {
    const parent = parentRef.current;
    const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
    const children = Array.from(parent.children);
    let outsideChildren = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      const childRect = children[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      if (childRect.right > parentRect.right) {
        outsideChildren.push(children[i]);
        parent.removeChild(children[i]);
      }
    }
    // Now "outsideChildren" contains the DOM nodes of the children outside the parent. 
    // You can create a new div and append these children to that div.
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    outsideChildren.forEach(child => {
      newDiv.appendChild(child);
    });
    // Append newDiv to the body or wherever you want it in your document
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div
        ref={parentRef}
        className="parent"
        style={{
          background: "blue",
          height: "100px",
          width: "500px",
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ background: "cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "23px" }}>
          E1
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "red", marginRight: "12px", width: "40px" }}>
          E2
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "23px" }}>
          E33
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "red", marginRight: "12px", width: "63px" }}>
          E4444
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "23px" }}>
          E555
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "red", marginRight: "12px", width: "113px" }}>
          E666666
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "53px" }}>
          E7
        </div>
        <div style={{ background: "red", marginRight: "12px", width: "33px" }}>
          E8
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E9
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E10
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E11
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E12
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E13
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E14
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E15
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E16
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E17
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E18
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E19
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ background: " cyan", marginRight: "12px", width: "43px" }}
        >
          E20
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This will remove all children that are outside of the parent div's right boundary and append them to a new div.
------------ recommended way -------

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef,useState,useEffect } from "react";

function Child({ color, width, children }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ background: color, marginRight: '12px', width: `${width}px` }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const parentRef = useRef(null);
  const initialChildren = [
    { color: 'cyan', width: 23, text: 'E1' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },
    { color: 'red', width: 40, text: 'E2' },

    // ...more children here...
  ];
  const [fitChildren, setFitChildren] = useState(initialChildren);
  const [overflowChildren, setOverflowChildren] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const parentWidth = 500; // The fixed width of your parent div
    let accumulatedWidth = 0;
    let fit = [];
    let overflow = [];
    
    initialChildren.forEach((child) => {
      accumulatedWidth += child.width + 12; // child width + margin
      if (accumulatedWidth <= parentWidth) {
        fit.push(child);
      } else {
        overflow.push(child);
      }
    });

    setFitChildren(fit);
    setOverflowChildren(overflow);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    <div className="parent" style={{ background: 'blue', height: '100px', width: '500px', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {fitChildren.map((child, index) => (
        <Child key={index} color={child.color} width={child.width}>
          {child.text}
        </Child>
      ))}
    </div>
    <div className="overflow" style={{ background: 'green', height: '100px', width: '500px', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      {overflowChildren.map((child, index) => (
        <Child key={index} color={child.color} width={child.width}>
          {child.text}
        </Child>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
     
   
  );
}
```

This version still only runs the check once after the initial render. If you're adding children dynamically, you would need to adapt this to respond to those changes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to scroll in the div,  for all outside elements I want to cut them and make another div with them ,bur before cutting I must calculate who is outside the parent div..

Comment: I see, you want to determine which children are outside the parent div's bounds and then create a new div with those elements. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: When I change my parent div's width the elements not displayed as wanted, I need to refresh each time to see the changes.. Have you an idea how to get ride of this ?

Comment: Directly manipulating the DOM in React is generally considered a bad practice, unless there are no other options. Consider redesigning your components in a more React-friendly way if possible.

Comment: Please, if it is answered, mark it as answered; thanks.

Comment: Please see my updated question, It's more react-friendly

Comment: @alainber82 can you not use flexbox with `flex-wrap: wrap` for this?

Comment: @Zachiah why not ? If othe solution work yes sure

Comment: @GregUretzky your last solution will work ONLY if I have one div per column, for my case I can have more than 1 div, so it will overflow when the last column has at least one div, and it's not what I want :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a React issue, I think it's more a Css issue that need a tricky solution..